# Minor in Disclosing Party of an NDA

Tags: minor, non-disclosure, disclosure

In an NDA, the Disclosing Party made a clause that any and all ideas generated by the Disclosing Part and labelled confidential are the property of the Disclosing Property and cannot be released without the consent of the Disclosing Party.

However, the individual in the Disclosing Party who had generated the ideas (and continues to do so) is a minor below the age of 18. I am concerned that there may be a law in there state of Rhode Island that may make it such that the child can't be apart of the Disclosing Party due to his status as a minor (of course, a guardian would sign for him). While I haven't found any laws indicating this, they may exist (our state is very poor with publishing this kind of information).

In order to make sure that the confidential information that may be developed during the term of the NDA remains available to the minor, would adding in a parent who is over 18 to the list of members in the Disclosing Party prevent the court from striking down the NDA under the premise that the Disclosing Party can't be made up of minors? In this case, I am guessing that the rights to the confidential information would solely go to the guardian in the Disclosing Party. Thank you.